# How SVD works to find similar blocks in image?

Tags: svd

I am writing a code to find out which part of an image has been duplicated, so i need to find similar blocks in image. I need to use SVD (singular value decomposition) to find which blocks match together . Do you know how i can apply SVD on image to find similar blocks?

Please help me . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

SVD can be used to compare images (blocks) by applying SVD to two images and then comparing only the SVD approximations of them, up to a certain order. This can extended to more than two images by treating the SVD result as a feature vector (-> machine learning) for e.g. [k-nearest neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) or [Cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).

SVD based image compression ("approximation") is e.g. described here: http://online.redwoods.cc.ca.us/instruct/darnold/laproj/fall2001/adamdave/textwriteup.pdf .

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer, but i need to find similar blocks in one image, when you copy some part of the image and paste it to another part it means two parts of image are same, i want to find those two part by using svd.

Comment: This is not how SVD works. For what you want to achieve SVD is not the right starting point, although it can be part of the solution. But: AFAICS, most approaches to your problem do usually not involve SVD.